# Select multiple image attachments at a time to attach to Notes&Attachments in the saleforce through vf pages

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

i did no of examples on attachments but in case of attching multiple image attachments to notes&attchments i face problem.please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

[How to upload multiple images into custom object or attachments from visualforce pages?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127385/how-to-upload-multiple-images-into-custom-object-or-attachments-from-visualforce)

Comment: Please can you show what code you have built to already attach files.  See the guidelines on [ask]

Comment: Here we are not able to select all files at a time. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127385/how-to-upload-multiple-images-into-custom-object-or-attachments-from-visualforce